# Can not get Twitter Bootstrap Flexbox to work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a simple form testing out FlexBox in Bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>

        </header>
        <nav>

        </nav>
        <main>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
                <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
                <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code I am using is above. You can simply cut and paste the code and it should work right out of the box. The HTML in question is the last div element in my main. It should be reversed and it is not. I have tried using ordering and that doesn't work. Something tells me there is something I missing but I am taking the examples straight from the tutorial page.

Any ideas?

Comment: All the currently classes you are trying to use (`d-flex`, `p-*` and `flex-row`) are not available on **Bootstrap 3.X** versions. Check how to download [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/) instead.

Comment: Just saw that! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Found out I am using version 3.x and not 4

For those you want to get version 4 on your pages here are the tags.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```